Convergence of linear functionals
Let $(\ell_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of linear functionals in $\mathrm{BV}^*$, namely the dual of the space of functions with bounded variation. Suppose that $\ell_n$ converges to $\ell$ as $n \to \infty$ in the strong topology on $\mathrm{BV}^*$. Now consider a sequence $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $f_n\in \mathrm{BV}$.
I am interested in the following question. Is it true that
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\ell_n(f_n)=\lim_{n\to \infty} \ell(f_n).$$
I think this is okay since $\ell_n$ converges strongly to $\ell$, but I am not entirely sure since the argument of the functionals also depend on the limiting parameter.

You will need $\sup_n |f_n|{BV} < \infty$, I think.  Then you estimate $$|(\ell_n-\ell)(f_n)| \le |\ell_n-\ell|{BV^*},|f_n|_{BV}$$

@GEdgar Perfect! I have a uniform bound on $||f_n||_{\mathrm{BV}}$ so this works well.

The conclusion does not hold unless $f_n$ is convergent. The condition $\sup_n\|f_n\|<\infty $ is not sufficient. In general let $\ell_n\in X^*,$ where $X$ is an infinite dimensional Banach space.  Assume $\ell_n\to 0=:\ell$ with respect to the strong topology in $X^*$ but  $\|\ell_n\|\not\to 0.$  WLOG we may assume $\|\ell_n\|\ge 2\delta>0$  for some $\delta. $ Thus there exists $g_n\in X$ so  that $\|g_n\|=1$ and $|\ell_n(g_n)|\ge \delta.$  Let $f_n= {g_n\over \ell_n(g_n)}.$ Then $\|f_n\|\le {1\over \delta}$ and $\ell_n(f_n)= 1.$  On the other hand $\ell(f_n)=0$ for all $n.$
The conclusion holds when $f_n$ is convergent. Indeed for $f_n\to f$ it follows from $$\ell_n(f_n) -\ell(f)=  [\ell_n(f_n) -\ell_n(f)] +[\ell_n(f) -\ell(f)]$$
